# Convert GMT date to other timezone date using offset

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I wanted to convert date which is in GMT to other Timezone date.
All i have is the offset of that timezone which is in following format `GMT+05:30`.

I have refereed many question but most of it was converting using timezone identifier.

How can i get this to work.
Thanks

Comment: Check this ..you will easily find tons of articles on google/stack etc http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimezone.php also check for supported timezones if you need at later http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php & start searching/reading from here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php

Comment: Its better to save the timezone instead of offset

Comment: Do you have the date as a string?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes it string in UTC format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC offset to timezone or date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820718/convert-utc-offset-to-timezone-or-date) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923569/php-echo-timezone-based-on-gmt-offset